# WinVerifyTrust returning CERT_E_CHAINING

Tags: c++, winapi, code-signing

Some Users are reporting that Desura (program that I develop) wont start due to the service returning the error code CERT_E_CHAINING when it tries to verify the code signing certificate.

Msdn reports this as: A chain of certificates was not correctly created.

I cant seem to work out what causes this or what this error means. Any ideas?

Comment: This one took a week of my life: https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/code-signing-support/index?page=content&id=SO16958&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1313006972482

Answer (score 4):

In the documentation of [WinVerifyTrust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the MSDN you can read

> For certificate verification, use the CertGetCertificateChain and
>   CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy functions.

The problem is that quite a few work should be done if one need to verify whether one certificate are permitted for code signing. First of all the certificate itself must by valid and it must has `szOID_PKIX_KP_CODE_SIGNING` ("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3"). Additionally its parent and the parent's parent should be OK. For example if the parent has only `szOID_PKIX_KP_CLIENT_AUTH` ("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2") in the Enhanced Key Usage or if the one from the parent certificates are relocated the certificate which you try to verify will be invalid. So the chain have to be build and the chain have to be verified.

Many interesting substitution can took place. For example, it can be that one from the parent certificates is expired now. On the other side the certificates will by typically not only signed, but the [Time Stamping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping) was used. So one can verify that the root certificate as the Issuer is expired now, but the root certificate was still valid at the time of issuing of the child certificate. If the time of the signing of the child certificate was proved by the corresponding time signature, and the Issued certificate is not yet expired the child certificate will be valid. I hope the example is not too complex. I want only show that not only every certificate in the chain should be verified, but *the whole chain should be validated*. Sorry for so long explanation.

I suppose, that `WinVerifyTrust` uses internally the functions `CertGetCertificateChain` and `CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy` in some ways, but with which parameters exactly it's not clear. Many things depend on the parameters of `WINTRUST_DATA` which you use.

In any way the error `CERT_E_CHAINING` can come from `CertGetCertificateChain`, `CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy` or any other API used internally. For example it can be from the `dwError` field of [CERT_CHAIN_POLICY_STATUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) used as `pPolicyStatus` parameter of `CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy`.

You wrote that "some Users are reporting" the error, so it can be that **the users try to use your application in the wrong way or some certificates are installed incorrectly**. If one export certificate for example one can do it together with parent certificates of without the parents. If one export certificate without parents the validation of the imported certificate will be a little more complex. In some situations the root certificate can be downloaded based on the URLs from the child certificate, but in other situation it will be impossible. If the parent certificate or the parent's parent can not be found or downloaded you will the `CERT_E_CHAINING` error.